# Cache Evict is not working

Tags: spring, caching

in my project, I am using a @Cacheable annotation ia a service method that returns results of calculation involving books and some marks, and i want to Evict Caching in a @Controller class method that adds a new book to the database, because this new one will be necessary to a new calculation.

Service class:
@Cacheable("metas")
`public ... calculate(){return calculation;}`

Controller class:
@RequestMapping
@CacheEvict(value="metas", allEntries=true)
`public void addNewBook();`

Why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have @EnableCaching in the root application context. This wont have an effect on the child DispatcherServlet application context. The @CacheEvict annotation on your controller wont be processed. Spring uses BeanPostProcessor to weave caching behaviour at runtime through the use of proxies. BeanPostProcessors are scoped per application context.

Move the addNewBook method definition and the cache metadata to your service class and call that method from the controller

Comment: can you be a little more specific? what is the cache metadata and how do you move it?